# Flask+ReactJS App is running locally but failing after deploying on Azure Web Service

Tags: reactjs, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a simple flask app with ReactJS as Frontend on Azure Web Service. Below is my dir structure:
[image: Flask+ReactJS App structure]

In locally, I can run this app by firing the below commands:

```
flask run <--Backend
npm start <--- Front end
```

In my server.py, I have ensured that this app can be accessed from outside:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug = True)
```

All things are running locally fine as expected. Then I deployed this to Azure App Service using Azure DevOps. I have also ensured the startup script as per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-startup-command):

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir flask-server server:flaskreactapp
```

Unfortunately, when I am browsing the url "https://mysampleapp.azurewebsites.net", nothing is showing up. Instead it is giving `Application Error`

Not able to understand what I am missing here.

Just a thought here, in  order to run this locally, I am firing two commands. But in Azure I   have no option for providing `npm start`.

I have never done such deployment hence I am completely novice.

Comment: the application error can be due to anything please the logs

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I am asking for the logs of the azure app service under the log stream tag

Comment: what you can do is dockerize the web app then deploy docker file this way you will not have to deal with any error during due to deployment to a cloud platform

Comment: @MohitGanorkar: Many thanks for your input. I am deploying the App using Azure DevOps. When you say dockerize, did you mean adding docker file in th root directory? But when I created the App Service, I had chosen "Code" as option. Should I change that to Docker?

Comment: yes add docker file create docker image and deploy refer this msdocs on it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux

Comment: ok. I tried this `az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8000` using Azure CLI. As per the container log, the issue seems to be port conflict. Hence I had resorted to this. However, no rescue so far.

Comment: Besides, docker is a paid product in an organization level. Hence can't take that route!.